# Routing not redirecting to the expected page

Tags: angular

I have the following routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  // Public layout
  {
    path: '',
    component: PublicLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
    ]
  },
  // Private layout
  {
    path: '',
    component: PrivateLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'logout', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'changelog', component: ChangelogComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    ],
  },
  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'changelog' }
];
```

So when I login if I navigate to `/changelog` everything work, from the configuration I would expect that calling / would redirect me to `changelog` but I'm always redirected to `/login`. I already checked that authguard is not the problem, and also if I navigate directly to changelog it works so authGuard is doing the right job. Is there something that I'm missing or not understanding?

I would expect that by default if authguard passes `/` would be redirect it to `changelog`.

Comment: I think problem in the path value. You should not have same value for both parent paths, as currently it is "".
So when you navigate to "/", it will never go to second route (private route). So it first try to resolve from the first path.  So here it will match & call the loginComponent children route & redirect to the login page.

Comment: So there are two possible ways do that -
1- In auth guard, check if page is login & session present, redirect to changelog.
2- Change the path value like "/auth" for first route & "" for second route & update code accordingly.
I suppose in this way, your issue can solve.

Comment: Seems you are giving same path for your private layout as well as for public  layout for my suggestion for public change "
path: 'home',
component: PublicLayoutComponent",
in case of public layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this symbol "**" in angular routing means "**anything else**". It redirects you to login component, because this route "/" exists (was **already** defined). As an example, if you type "/literallyAnythingElse", then you'l get redirected to "changelog".